# How to change the color of an image in photoshop

Tags: adobe, photoshop, masking, editing, ui-design

I am a newbie in Photoshop and struggling to change the colour of these logos. *(These are not texts. They are imported images).*

I tried making a layer mask and for some reason, it didn't change the colour at all from the solid colour fill.

[image: The Image I want to edit]

[image: The layers I'm currently having]

Comment: You need to ask this on [graphic design stackexchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) as it's not a code based question. Also show what properties of the hue/saturation are set.  And to make it easier explain what your want to change the colour to exactly - you've changed the Google logo from multi coloured to black - doesn't that answer your own question?

Comment: perfectly valid question, but belongs on another Stack Exchange site https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/, however that is not in the list. Can it be migrated please?